# Saving to CoreData in a loop

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a list of json objects that I want to write into CoreData. Json objects are coming from API. I have a method to Upsert a data into CoreData. The code for that is the following.

```
public class func upsertSetting (resultsArr : NSArray, settingTypeId: Int, countryId: Int) {
    if let moc = CoreDataHelper().managedObjectContext {

        var settings : [Setting]
        settings = resultsArr as [Setting]

        var existingSettings : [SettingCoreDataModel]?
        existingSettings = fetchAllSettings(settingTypeId, countryId: countryId)

        for result in settings {

            var key = result.key
            var value = result.value
            if (value == nil)
            {
                value = ""
            }

            var id = result.id
            var settingTypeId = result.settingTypeId
            var countryId = result.countryId



            var settingCoreData: [SettingCoreDataModel]?
            var existingSetting: SettingCoreDataModel?

            if(existingSettings? == nil){
                existingSetting = nil
            }
            else{
                settingCoreData = filter(existingSettings!) { (e:SettingCoreDataModel) in e.key == key }
                if(settingCoreData? != nil && settingCoreData?.count > 0){
                existingSetting = settingCoreData?.first
                }
            }
            if(existingSetting == nil){                    
                SettingCoreDataModel.createInManagedObjectContext(moc, key: key!, value: value!, id: id!, settingTypeId: settingTypeId!, countryId: countryId!)
            }
            else if(existingSetting?.value != value!){
                existingSetting?.value = value!
                save()
            }
        }
    }
}

public class func save() {
    var error : NSError?
    if !CoreDataHelper().managedObjectContext!.save(&error) {
       println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

`fetchAllSettings` looks like this:

```
public class func fetchAllSettings (settingTypeId: Int, countryId: Int) -> [SettingCoreDataModel]?
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SettingCoreDataModel")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "settingTypeId == %d AND countryId == %d", settingTypeId, countryId)

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    if let fetchResults = CoreDataHelper().managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [SettingCoreDataModel] {
        return fetchResults
    }
    else{
        return []
    }
}
```

And here is the `SettingCoreDataModel` with `createInManagedObjectContext` :

```
public class SettingCoreDataModel: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var key: String
@NSManaged var value: String
@NSManaged var id: NSNumber
@NSManaged var settingTypeId: NSNumber
@NSManaged var countryId: NSNumber

class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, key: NSString, value: NSString, id: int, settingTypeId: int, countryId: int) -> SettingCoreDataModel {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("SettingCoreDataModel", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as? SettingCoreDataModel
        newItem?.key = key
        newItem?.value = value
        newItem?.id = id
        newItem?.settingTypeId = settingTypeId
        newItem?.countryId = countryId

        return newItem!
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I call `createInManagedObjectContext` it does not seem to be saving into CoreData. I couldn't figure the issue and I'm fairly new to `Swift` and `XCode`

Edit: One thing I forgot to mention is that, I'm trying to create a plugin with this. All my code is in Pod but my data model is in example project. I'm not sure if that makes any difference to that, but while fetching and everything it seems to be working fine.

Using `save()` didn't help either by the way.

I call `upsertSetting` on `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. After that, on my first view I try to get a single record by key and use it on the table view:

```
var textColorSetting: Setting?   
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
textColorSetting = SettingCoreData.fetchSetting("text_color", countryId: 3)
}
```

Table cells:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

    textColorSetting = SettingCoreData.fetchSetting("text_color", countryId: 3)

   var textColor = textColorSetting?.value

    if (textColor? == nil){
        textColor = "#ff00ff"
    }
    let color = SettingCoreDataModel.hexStringToUIColor(textColor!)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = color
}
```

Fetching single setting:

```
public class func fetchSetting(key : NSString, countryId: Int) -> Setting? {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SettingCoreDataModel")

    var existingSetting: SettingCoreDataModel?

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@ AND countryId == %d", key, countryId)

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    var error: NSError?

    if let fetchResults = CoreDataHelper().managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [SettingCoreDataModel] {
        println(fetchResults.count)
        if (!fetchResults.isEmpty && fetchResults.count > 0) {
            existingSetting = fetchResults.first!
            var setting: Setting?
            setting?.id = existingSetting?.id as? Int
            setting?.key = existingSetting?.key
            setting?.value = existingSetting?.value
            setting?.settingTypeId = existingSetting?.settingTypeId as? Int
            setting?.countryId = existingSetting?.countryId as? Int
            return setting
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

In here `println(fetchResults.count)` always prints 0. That's why I assume `save()` is not working.

Comment: Why don't you call save() there too? Inserting new objects into CoreData also requires a call to save on the managedObjectContext.

Comment: @shim It doesn't work either way. I tried like that as well. Besides, before I moved my code to this format, I wasn't using save and it was working fine. I think it might worth mentioning that, I'm trying to create a plugin with this code. I'm not sure if the issue is related to that.

Comment: Then perhaps we need to examine what you mean by "doesn't work"  What criteria are you using to determine that it didn't work?  Simplify your code down to a minimal example case and clearly explain what results you expect and what results you get and how they differ.

Comment: I'm editing my code to show where I'm trying to fetch single record and get a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you create a new setting, you need to invoke save (or better yet, take save out of the inside of the loop and just call it once after the loop)

```
if(existingSetting == nil){                    
    SettingCoreDataModel.createInManagedObjectContext(moc, key: key!, value: value!, id: id!, settingTypeId: settingTypeId!, countryId: countryId!)
    save()    // this is missing
}
```

Some other observations and simplifications:

`fetchAllSettings` will always return a valid array (possibly empty) of settings, declare it as `-> [SettingCoreDataModel]` instead of declaring it as an optional:

```
public class func fetchAllSettings (settingTypeId: Int, countryId: Int) -> [SettingCoreDataModel]

var existingSettings = fetchAllSettings(settingTypeId, countryId: countryId)
```

having done that you can use the fact that first returns an optional to simplify the logic to find an existing setting to:

```
var existingSetting = existingSettings.filter({ (e:SettingCoreDataModel) in e.key == key }).first
```

To insure that value always has a valid value, so you don't have to worry about unwrapping it, use nil checking:

```
var value = result.value ?? ""
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. One thing I forgot to mention is that, I'm creating plugin with this code and my data model is in example project.